# xlwt and xlutils not working while xlrd works all right

Tags: python, excel, importerror, xlwt, xlutils

I am a Windows user and I have a Python 2.7 version. I would be really grateful if someone helped me on that: I have downloaded, unpacked with 7Zip and installed *xlrd*, *xlwt* and *xlutils* (the installation seemed to be completed all right) but only *xlrd* works. Even short commands like `from xlwt import *` result in an error, e.g.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fanny/Desktop/python/excel_28.01.w.o.utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from xlwt import *
  File "C:/Users/fanny/Desktop/python\xlwt.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xlutils.copy import copy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.0-py2.7.egg\xlutils\copy.py", line 7, in <module>
    from xlutils.filter import process,XLRDReader,XLWTWriter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.0-py2.7.egg\xlutils\filter.py", line 17, in <module>
    from xlwt.Style import default_style
ImportError: No module named Style
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file named `xlwt.py` in your working directory, which is the first place the `import` statement checks. Python will try loading a `Style` module from there and of course not find any.

The best solution here is to **rename your local `xlwt.py` file to a non-conflicting name**.

See: [Python 2 Docs: 6.1.2. The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)